# Is it possible to combine two js.Dynamic objects

Tags: scala.js

Say I have

```
val obj1 = js.Dynamic.literal(attr1 = "x")
val obj2 = js.Dynamic.literal(attr2 = "y")
```

and I would like to combine obj1 and obj2 to yield and object of

```
{attr1 = "x", attr2 = "y"}
```

Does js.Dynamic have a method to yield such a combination?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no existing method doing that. In ES6 there is [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), but it is not supported in IE.

I recommend re-implementing it in Scala.js:

```scala
def mergeJSObjects(objs: js.Dynamic*): js.Dynamic = {
  val result = js.Dictionary.empty[Any]
  for (source <- objs) {
    for ((key, value) <- source.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[Any]])
      result(key) = value
  }
  result.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic]
}
```

And now you can simply do

```scala
mergeJSObjects(obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: Works perfectly except had to modify the result instantiation as js.Dictionary is an abstract class: val result = js.Object.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[Any]]

Comment: Oops, indeed it should have been `val result = js.Dictionary.empty[Any]`. I fixed my answer. (definitely not `js.Object.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[Any]]`, though! That means you're reusing the global `Object` object over and over again)

Answer (score 0):

I put the same question to the scala.js forums and was pointed to `js.Object.assign`